# php select-option post back retain value

Tags: php

I have a form with input type-select
however when page submit and post back with error message
The select value is clean, I try to use radio button (checked unchecked) to retain the value,
yet it is not working.

```
//HTML///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
<select name="age">
     <option value="">Age</option>
     <option value="14-17" <?PHP echo $age_14; ?>>14 - 17</option>
     <option value="18-29" <?PHP echo $age_18; ?>>18 - 29</option>
</select>

//PHP////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$age_14="unchecked";
$age_18="unchecked";

$age=$_POST['age'];
  if($age=='14-17'){$age_14="checked";}
  else if($age=='18-29'){$age_18="checked";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `select` tag you have to use `selected="selected"` not `checked`.

Try with:

```
$age_14 = "";
$age_18 = "";

$age = $_POST['age'];
if ($age == '14-17') {
    $age_14 = 'selected="selected"';
} elseif ($age == '18-29') { 
    $age_18 = 'selected="selected"';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `select` boxes, the attribute is `selected`, not `checked`. You also do not need the `unchecked` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `checked` attribute. You need to use `selected`:

```
$age=$_POST['age'];
$age_14 = $age=='14-17'?"selected":"";
$age_18 = $age=='18-29'?"selected":"";
```